# Python program wont go through entire input file

Tags: python, list, file

Write a program that first asks the user for the names of input and output files. Assuming the input file will have one integer per line, the program should write to the output file in each line: the number from the input file, its square, its cube and its square root separated by spaces. Currently i am stuck where my code only reads one line of the input text file and then stops.

```
def main():
    import math
    print("This program creates a file of Output numbers from a")
    print("File of input numbers")

    # Get the file names
    infileName = input("What file are the numbers in ? ")
    outfileName = input("What file should the new usernames go in ? ")

    #Open the files
    infile = open(infileName, "r")
    outfile = open(outfileName, "w")

    #Process each line of the input file
    for number in infile.readlines():
        #get the numbers from the line
        Num = float(number)
        #Square the number
        Square = (Num ** 2)
        #Cube the number
        Cube = (Num ** 3)
        #Squareroot of number
        Root = (math.sqrt(Num))
        #Write it to output file
        print(Root, ",", Cube, ",", Square, file = outfile)

    #Close both files
        infile.close()
        outfile.close()

        print("Numbers have been written to", outfileName) 

main()
```

Comment: For future reference, variable names should begin with a lower case letter; upper case first letters are for classes.

Comment: it's 'just' an indentation mistake.but indentation is essential in python

Answer (score 4):

You close both files during every (the first) iteration of the loop.
You need to remove some spaces so they are on the same level as `for`, and thus happen after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
with open(infileName, 'r') as f:
    nums = f.readlines()

for num in nums:
    ...
```